# .Net 5 Web Api, default System.Text.Json serialization is replaced by Newtonsoft.Json without specifying in startup.cs

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

How to avoid System.Text.Json to be replaced by Newtonsoft.Json, when send response from controller. When i testing my application i found json serialized by Newtonsoft.Json without specifying any where.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve], or at least as much detail as possible about how your problem arose and how you were able to prove that Json.NET was used instead of System.Text.Json.  As it is your question is unlikely to be answered due to lack of detail.  See: [ask].

Comment: There's no way this will happen by itself. Either your code or one of the packages you use requires and configures JSON.NET

Comment: BTW .NET (Core) 5 reaches End-Of-Life in less than 1 month, on May 2022. You should migrate to .NET 6 as soon as possible. .NET 6 is a long-term-support release while .NET 5 was only supported for 1 year